# Force not working in non-interactive mode

Tags: powershell

```
Deleting folder 'C:\agent\_work\2\a\Foo\_PublishedWebsites\Foo\sourcejs'

Remove-Item : Windows PowerShell is in NonInteractive mode. Read and Prompt functionality is not available.
At C:\agent\_work\2\s\Build\Deployment\PrepareWebsites.ps1:29 char:2
+ Remove-Item -Path $source -Force -Confirm:$false | Where { $_.PSIsContainer }
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Remove-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Process completed with exit code 1 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream.
```

I have tried adding -Force and -Confirm:$false but I still get this error. Using TFS 2015 builds. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Where is your command? Do you use `-Recurse`?

Comment: Thanks, the -Recurse flag was missing. Original command was as above: Remove-Item -Path $source -Force -Confirm:$false | Where { $_.PSIsContainer }

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Remove-Item -path 'C:\agent\_work\2\a\Foo\_PublishedWebsites\Foo\sourcejs\*' -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue -Verbose
```

Comment: Believe it or not, the most important bit is `-Recurse`.

Comment: Please explain why this works. Code only answers should not have 21 upvotes.

Comment: From the MS [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.3#notes): When you try to delete a folder that contains items without using the Recurse parameter, the cmdlet prompts for confirmation. Using -Confirm:$false doesn't suppress the prompt. This is by design.